# getting exception "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"?

Tags: iphone, exception, nsmutablearray, uidatepicker

i am getting start date and end date from user via date pickerview. when user scroll the pickerview in speed then it crashes there and gives me this exception. so whats the solution?

[

```
NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x013fabe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0154f5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x013f06e5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   iFeel                               0x0001e1b7 -[S7GraphView drawRect:] + 5714
    4   UIKit                               0x0047d6eb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 426
    5   QuartzCore                          0x01f6f9e9 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 143
    6   QuartzCore                          0x01f6f5ef _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 85
    7   QuartzCore                          0x01f6edea CABackingStoreUpdate + 2246
    8   QuartzCore                          0x01f6e134 -[CALayer _display] + 1085
    9   QuartzCore                          0x01f6dbe4 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 231
    10  QuartzCore                          0x01f6038b _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 325
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01f600d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01f907d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x013dbfbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x013710e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01339bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01339240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01339161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x019de268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x019de32d GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x0045442e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  iFeel                               0x00002990 main + 102
    22  iFeel                               0x00002921 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

the method @deepak and @ Grady Player are talking about is this:

```
-(void)getGraphicalData{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    self.friendBL = [[FriendBL alloc] init];
    self.result = [self.friendBL  getGraphicalData1:txtStartTime.text andTodate:txtEndTime.text];
    if ([self.result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        UIAlertView * friendListAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Friend List" message:(NSString*) self.result delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [friendListAlertView show];
        [friendListAlertView release];
    }
    else {
        self.reportList = (NSMutableArray*) self.result;
        NSLog(@"%d",[reportList count]);
    }
    [pool release];
}
```

after selecting date i click on button to say done and this is the code

```
-(IBAction)doneBtn{

    [dateView setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateTimePicker date]);
    NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    dateFormat.locale = locale;
    if (tag) {
        txtEndTime.text=[dateFormat stringFromDate:[dateTimePicker date]];
        if (![self compareDates]) {
            txtStartTime.text=@"";
            txtEndTime.text=@"";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Date is not in valid" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

    }
    else {
        txtStartTime.text=[dateFormat stringFromDate:[dateTimePicker date]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:[dateTimePicker date]]);



}
```

but if i pick a the date slowly it do not crashes

Comment: Can you add the `drawRect:` method of `S7GraphView`?

Comment: it is coming from the S7GraphView not the picker view, you must be handing some garbage data to it.

Comment: @Deepak, It is something hosted on googlecode, http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

Comment: @Grady Player, Didn't know that. Looks like an issue with the data source methods then. @Mashhadi, how have you implemented the data source methods?

Comment: u have posted my method and i am using s7graphview code from google. when i select the date slowly then it do not crashes but if i touch it in fast speed then it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not calling the method by thread you don't have to use an autorelease pool. Can you try this following code.

```
-(void)getGraphicalData{
    self.friendBL = [[[FriendBL alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.result = [self.friendBL  getGraphicalData1:txtStartTime.text andTodate:txtEndTime.text];
    if ([self.result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        UIAlertView * friendListAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Friend List" message:(NSString*) self.result delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [friendListAlertView show];
        [friendListAlertView release];
    }else {
        self.reportList = (NSMutableArray*) self.result;
        NSLog(@"%d",[reportList count]);
    }
}
```

This is my last try to help :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have an array without any objects in it and you're attempting to access the first object. If you show us code we can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In the above function you are not releasing the object FriendBL. How are you storing your property? Retain or assign or copy ?

Might be the problem with autorelease pool. Is the function called on a main thread ?

If you can give us more insight it might be useful.

Comment: i have added some more code. i am really amazed that y it is crashing on scrolling fastly why not on slow scroll?

Comment: I think the issue is mainly on the function getGraphicalData. Please give me the details of the properties self.friendBL and self.result. In the same time how are you calling the function getGraphicalData. Can you check if that function is being called in main thread using  [NSThread isMainThread]. When you use autorelease pool in a fast loop it can create some unusual error. I really hope I can help you more.

Comment: so ice of you for helping me. i am calling method in this way
}
-(IBAction)graphicalBtnClick{
 if ([txtStartTime.text length]>0&&[txtEndTime.text length]>0) {
  [self getGraphicalData];
 }
 GraphicalVC *graphView=[[GraphicalVC alloc] initFromGraphical:reportList];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:graphView animated:YES];
}
i am using property retain for both but i think i should use NSThread here instead of calling method directly.